# Router doesn't route to component after refresh angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the problem that if I reload my application with a url that should show a specific component my application will instead show the default page. For example I want to go to /create/user directly over the browser (refresh) he will instead show me my default page.

Here is my route config.

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';
import {GenericRequestEndpoint} from './components/dynamicresponsetable/dynamicresponsetable.component';
import {DynamicDisplayForm} from './components/dynamicdisplaycomponent/dynamic.display.component';
import {DynamicCreationComponent} from './components/dynamiccreationcomponent/dynamic.creation.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './components/login/login.component';
import {AuthService} from './components/services/auth.service';
import {AuthGuard} from './components/services/auth-guard.service';
import {Dummy} from './components/dummy';
import {ConfigurationComponent} from './components/configurationcomponent/configuration.component';


export const ROUTER: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: Dummy,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'endpoint/:endpointname',
        component: GenericRequestEndpoint,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'detail/:specificitem',
        component: DynamicDisplayForm,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'create/:endpointname',
        component: DynamicCreationComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'configurator/:endpointname',
        component: ConfigurationComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }
];



export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(ROUTER), AuthService, AuthGuard
];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use an empty path `''`, without child routes, then add `pathMatch`

```
{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

Comment: It didn't work. Maybe I have to give a better example. Imagine a user sends a link to another user. For example http://localhost:3000/create/user. Now my problem is that Angular isn't redirecting to my DynamicCreationComponent. The router is just empty.

Comment: What server are you using? Is this happening with `ng serve`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "The router is just empty"?

Comment: Ok sry it displays the login component. I didn't saw it because I was logged in

Comment: Does this mean it's working? or is there still a problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I would like that he displays the component, that the user wants but he always goes to the LoginComponent. Also if the user types in another url into the browser.

Comment: Do your `AuthService` or `AuthGuard` do any redirects?

Comment: No. The only redirect is when the user wants to log out

Comment: Have you set a base HREF like `<base href="/">` or `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}`?

Comment: do i have to add this in my app.constant?

Comment: You could try adding the later to `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS`. For the default setup you don't need it AFAIK. If might hurt if you have it with a different value than `/` - which is why I asked.

Comment: ok thanks for your effort but I have solved it with another solution. It may not be the cleanest method but it works